# How to access both incoming stdout and stderr pipelines from inside python?

Tags: python, bash, pipe, pipeline

In a bash script, I can access the pipes interchangeably.  If I would like to do this from within a python script, how would I go about accessing `sys.stderr`?

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import sys

std_input = sys.stdin.readlines()
std_error = sys.stderr.readlines() # <-- fails, complaining that the file is 
                                   #     not open for reading.
```

And I call the code from within a bash script:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash 
... | ./python-script.py
```

Where there exists both `stdin` and `stderr` content on the pipeline streaming into the `python-script.py` command.

There is no need for concurrency or anything fancy.

Comment: You need "concurrency or something fancy" to ensure you don't deadlock because you're blocking on a read to one pipe while the subprocess is blocking on a write to the other. Do you need the data *streamed* or is just *buffering* all the data and reading at the end sufficient? If the latter, `subprocess.run` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wait, you're streaming *into* the Python process? There is only one `stdin`. There is no standard stream for "error in", only "error out" (`stderr`). If you want to feed `stdout` and `stderr` from one process into `stdin` of another, you just need to redirect `stderr` into `stdout`. The data gets mixed into a single stream, which you can read on the other end from `stdin`.

Comment: @DanielPryden sounds like I’ll need to use Bash as a wrapper then,  thanks for explaining that